# mosh false-positive MITM attack warning

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn

I connect my laptop to the office network via openvpn (under subnet 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0).  And I can ssh and mosh into my office desktop no problem.

Recently I decided to also make a second openvpn network on different subnet (192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0) for accessing my computers at home.

When I am connected to both networks:

```
$ ip address 
...
4: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.26 peer 10.8.0.25/32 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.2.3 peer 192.168.20.4/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I tried to ssh into my office desktop. `$ ssh officebox` works (officebox resolves to 172.22.22.133 is in the office router IP range), but my preferred method `$ mosh officebox` failed:

```
$ mosh officebox
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:Qcg8zcFGJAUwtnb1c/oATrVTIdRoFK/neQF7fmK/mag.
Please contact your system administrator.
... ... ...
/usr/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message.
```

However, directly using IP address `$ mosh 172.22.22.133` works.

So I suspect this is somehow DNS related.  If I comment out the client-side `up/down update-resolv-conf` lines in OpenVPN `home.conf` line so that a `nameserver` line is not inserted in `/etc/resolve.conf`, mosh by hostname is back to normal.  I am wondering what is causing mosh to think that remote host signature has changed.

```
# server.ovpn:
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca   home/ca.crt
cert home/server.crt
key  home/server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh home/dh2048.pem
server 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist home-ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
client-config-dir home/ccd
learn-address /etc/openvpn/learn-address.sh
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN home-vpn.net"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.2.1"
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth home/ta.key 0 # This file is secret
comp-lzo
user vpn
group vpn
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-home-status.log
log         openvpn-home.log
verb 3
up   update-resolv-conf
down update-resolv-conf
```